# Python Django: getting data from modal gives <built-in function id> error

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to get a value from a modal, that gets the value using jQuery from a list.

Let's explain.

I have a list of objects in an HTML page using a for loop, and in each row, there is a delete button.

This delete button launches a confirmation Modal.

To get the id of the row and use it in the Modal, I use jQuery:

```
{% for a in objects %}
[...]
<td><button type="button" class="delete-button" data-name="{{ a.id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button></td>
[...]
{% endfor %}

[...]

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal">
[...]
<form action="{% url 'delete_object' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="object_id" name="object_field" />
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
[...]

<script>
    $('.delete-button').click(function() {
        $('#object_id').html($(this).data('name'))
    })
</script>
```

Without explaining the urls.py part, let's get straight to the view, which is quite simple:

```
def cancel_request(request):
    _id = request.POST.get("object_id")
    obj = Object.objects.get(id=id)
    obj.status = "Annulé"
    obj.save()
    return redirect("home")
```

When I run the modal, I make sure I can see the id value getting in the modal, but when I try to put it in an input, I cannot see it anymore. If I put it in an h5 tag for example: `<h5 class="modal-title" id="request_id" name="requestid_kw"></h5>`, it shows on the modal, but still does not get passed through to the view. When I execute the button, I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /cr
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/cr

Django Version: 4.1.3
Python Version: 3.10.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'api.apps.ApiConfig',
 'import_export',
 'storages']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2018, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'builtin_function_or_method') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\django\views.py", line 68, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\paylik-v1\main\views.py", line 443, in cancel_request
    avance = Advance.objects.get(id=id)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 636, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1420, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1438, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1445, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1532, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1562, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1478, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1303, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 341, in get_prep_lookup
    return super().get_prep_lookup()
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 85, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "D:\#######\v1proj\v1env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2020, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(

Exception Type: TypeError at /cr
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
```

Comment: It's a typo in `obj = Object.objects.get(id=id)`: `id=id` → `id=_id`

Comment: Dear Kaiss B. I already corrected this typo in the below answer.

Comment: It's not the issue cuz actually I changed the code before putting it here.

Answer (score 0):

I could see one mistake, you defined `name` two times in hidden input field inside form tag of Html, and also you haven't provided any `value` attribute, and you should also use `@require_POST` decorator on the view. By looking at jQuery code it seems following will be the right code try it.

Template file:

```py
{% for a in objects %}
[...]
<td><button type="button" class="delete-button" data-name="{{ a.id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button></td>
[...]
{% endfor %}

[...]

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal">
[...]
<form action="{% url 'delete_object' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="object_id" name="object_field" value="some_id_needs_to_be_passed_here"/> 
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
[...]

<script>
    $('.delete-button').click(function() {
        $('#object_id').html($(this).data('name'))
    })
</script>
```

views.py

```py
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def cancel_request(request):
    id = request.POST.get("object_field")
    obj = get_object_or_404(Object, id=id)
    obj.status = "Annulé"
    obj.save()
    return redirect("home")
```

Comment: I don't understand the value="some_id_......" I get the value from the jQuery, how can I pass it to the view using the field name  object_field?

Comment: @KaissB. You need to pass some id in `value` attribute through which you'll be able to delete in `can_request_view`.